# Using reCAPTCHA with Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, recaptcha

I'm trying to use this example of classic ASP but I have 2 pages, one is form page, the other is verify page. I'm a total newb at classic ASP so I'm not sure if I'm making some syntax errors or not.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/asp

On my form page, I'm loading reCAPTCHA via JS and that part is working fine. On the verify page, I have the code below.

Main code (I removed stuff from Google that I wasn't going to use like generate a recaptcha form field with ASP)

```
  recaptcha_challenge_field  = Request.Form("recaptcha_challenge_field")
  recaptcha_response_field   = Request.Form("recaptcha_response_field")
  recaptcha_public_key       = "hidden" //your public key
  recaptcha_private_key      = "hidden" //your private key

  // returns "" if correct, otherwise it returns the error response
  function recaptcha_confirm(rechallenge,reresponse)

  Dim VarString
  VarString = _
          "privatekey=" & recaptcha_private_key & _
          "&remoteip=" & Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") & _
          "&challenge=" & rechallenge & _
          "&response=" & reresponse

  Dim objXmlHttp
  Set objXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  objXmlHttp.open "POST", "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify", False
  objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  objXmlHttp.send VarString

  Dim ResponseString
  ResponseString = split(objXmlHttp.responseText, vblf)
  Set objXmlHttp = Nothing

  if ResponseString(0) = "true" then
    'They answered correctly
     recaptcha_confirm = ""
  else
    'They answered incorrectly
     recaptcha_confirm = ResponseString(1)
  end if

  end function

  server_response = ""
  newCaptcha = True
  if (recaptcha_challenge_field <> "" or recaptcha_response_field <> "") then
    server_response = recaptcha_confirm(recaptcha_challenge_field, recaptcha_response_field)
    newCaptcha = False
  end if
```

This is where I'm trying to detect if captcha is correct, but it submits form either way.

```
    if recaptcha_response_field <> "" AND newCaptcha = False then
// submit form
Else
  Response.Write "Error: Please fill out all form fields correctly."  
End If
```

Comment: don't you have to query the Server_response variable instead of the recaptcha_response_field variable? because the recaptcha_response_field is fielled wth the request.form Parameter and is of course <> "" because the user has entered a value?

Comment: I tried that but that still allows the form to submit.

Answer (score 0):

Well looks like I had to do it this way:

```
If server_response = "" AND newCaptcha = False then
    // Captcha correct 
ElseIf server_response <> "" OR newCaptcha then
    // Captcha incorrect
Else
    // Some other form error
End If
```