# i have my form in html and on post it is using asp classic , i want to use google recaptcha in my form

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have made my form in html and using the post method to send the mail using classic asp, I want to apply google recaptcha in my form, I have applied the site key in the html but how should i apply it in my server side to get the g-recaptcha-response

```
<%
dim  name,email,message
name = Request.Form("name")
email = Request.Form("email")
message = Request.Form("message")
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Enquiry Form"
myMail.From="xyz@example.com"
myMail.To= "xyz@example.com"
myMail.Cc="xyz@example.com"
myMail.HtmlBody="<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td>Name:</td><td>" + name + "</td></tr><tr><td>Email:</td><td >" + email + "</td></tr><tr><td>Message:</td><td >" + message + "</td></tr></table>"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="webmail.example.com"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="xyz@example.com"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="123456789"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
'End of remote SMTP server configuration section
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
'response.Write("<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td>Name:</td><td>" + name + "</td></tr><tr><td>Email:</td><td >" + email + "</td></tr><tr><td>Message:</td><td >" + message + "</td></tr></table>"
'response.End()
%>
```

Comment: Have you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711884/how-to-implement-google-recaptcha-2-0-in-asp-classic  and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694036/using-recaptcha-with-classic-asp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement Google Recaptcha 2.0 in ASP Classic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711884/how-to-implement-google-recaptcha-2-0-in-asp-classic)